# Converting a hex string to int with same formatting

Tags: c++

I have a string:

```
string s = "0x10"
```

I want to find a way to convert this to an `int` with the same value, that is:

```
int x = 0x10
```

I'm getting the string `"0x10"` from the following code when using `cout << s`:
:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << "0x" << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << int(h) << endl;
string s = stream.str();
```

I get the right result if using `int h = 16` (which is `0x10` in hex)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: just so we understand. The code you show is to make the string "0x10". You want to know how to convert "0X10" to 16?

Comment: I think the OP wants the integer 16 to somehow remember to be printed as 0x10 when `cout` is used to output. Although the code example makes this more confusing.

Comment: `0x10 == 16 == 0b10000 == 020`  They all represent the same thing.  It is how you display them that matters.

Comment: No i want to convert 16 to 0x10 as an int. that is int x = 0x10;

Comment: 0x10 is 16 is sixteen is seize is.. It's the same number. If you want to print a number with the same format you've read it, you have to either (1) remember **two** things, the number itself and the formatting that was used when you've read it *or* (2) do away with numbers and just deal with strings.

Comment: No conversion is needed. They are all the same thing.

Comment: @Johannes-andriesCoetzee: That doesn't make sense. `int x = 16` and `int x = 0x10` do the same thing - they put the number "sixteen" into the variable called `x`. The base is literally irrelevant, and cannot be "remembered" or "stored" here.

Comment: Okay i think i am starting to understand. When I write to a hex file with ofstream it will write it in hex format due to the nature of the ofstream, this is 'std::ofstream ofile("somegds.gds", std::ios::binary | std::ofstream::app);'

Comment: If it is a text file then I you may be interested in outputting hex as text. If it is a binary file it (the base) makes no difference.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you. I realise now how this works.

Comment: Oh wait, I thought `base` defaulted to zero on `stoi.  For auto base detect, that would automatically interpret the '0x' part of the input string, it would work something like `std::string s("0x10");  int x = std::stoi( s, NULL, 0);`

Comment: @Johannes-andriesCoetzee: No, not really, unless you deliberately used `std::hex` and streamed in formatted output mode. Without seeing your actual code we have no way of knowing how you magically ended up with hex. More than likely, you're simply viewing the file's binary contents in a convenient hex form.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41223465/1889329), and it looks like you still haven't decided to wrap your head around the concepts of *encoding* and *presentation* of data. Those are different concepts, and you keep insisting, that you need the latter where it doesn't make **any** sense. You need to fix your mental model.

Answer (score -4):

its the reverse of what u have

```
istringstream iss(s);
int x;
iss >> hex >>  x;
```

or `std::stoi`

Seems like maybe you are confused - saying you want 0x10 in the int rather that 16. Thats a matter of how you convert the int to a string. The int is always 0b00010000 in memory

Comment: How did you get to 18.1k writing answers like this?

Comment: what did i do wrong? Is my istream use wrong (a little rusty)

Comment: Your answer is creeping towards something relevant and useful now, but it certainly wasn't either of those things to begin with. It also has presentation problems. inb4 "I'm on my phone" okay then wait until you're not!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i know OP is confused. But he did  ask - 'how to convert string in hex to int'. I showed that. (Once I fixed missing hex marker). I was waiting to see if he comment 'Yea but that prints 16 I want 0x10', to see if I understood his problem / misundertsanding.

Comment: So you intended to ask for clarification? Then that should be a _comment_.

Comment: i did that too.